# MVC5 how to use async to perform a progressive task?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await

I have a need. I have an MVC5 website. i am using normal contorller-model structure. Where I execute a controller function from Javascript. I have to process some xml files as they are uploaded. What happens when the controller executes the function for the first time it doesnt come back to the browser until all the xml files are processed.

So here is what i want. I want to execute controller function to execute model method. In that method i want pick all xml files and then i want asynchronously process them. here is the code:

```
var raw = new DirectoryInfo(xconfig.Directory.FullName + "//raw");
if (raw.Exists)
{
    var xmls = raw.GetFiles("*.xml");
    foreach (var xml in xmls)
    {
        if(ProcessedXmlFiles != null)
        {
            if(!ProcessedXmlFiles.Contains(xml.Name))
            {

                ExportData(xml);
                ProcessedXmlFiles.Add(xml.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the above code is executing, I call another javascript method to get the updates how many files have been processed using normal ajax call. So I just call another contrller method where I return the ProcessedXmlFiles.Count to know how many of them have been processed so far!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make your action return a `Task` and place your process inside a [Task.Run](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/).

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyAction(object param)
{
    var raw = new DirectoryInfo(xconfig.Directory.FullName + "//raw");
    if (raw.Exists)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => 
        {
            var xmls = raw.GetFiles("*.xml");
            foreach (var xml in xmls)
            {
                if(ProcessedXmlFiles != null)
                {
                    if(!ProcessedXmlFiles.Contains(xml.Name))
                    {
                        ExportData(xml);
                        ProcessedXmlFiles.Add(xml.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        // Do something
    }

    return View();
}
```

EDIT: Since OP seems to be expecting a different behavior than what asynchronous programming can offer, I suggest using a background worker instead but take note that using background workers in web apps is not desirable. ASP.NET works in a request-response manner. I suggest letting the user wait for the process to end before rendering the view.

```
public ActionResult MyAction(object param)
{
    ExecuteBackgroundWorker(param); // your model containing the method you want to execute
    return View(); // This will return the view while the background worker proceeds.
}

public void ExecuteBackgroundWorker(object param)
{
    BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgWorker.DoWork += bgWorker_DoWork;
    bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(param);
}

void bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do Something when work ends
}

void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var OPsModel = (MyModel)e.Argument; // Cast object back to original model
    OPsModel.ExecuteProcess(); // Execute the process
}
```

Comment: well that code is well inside a model and it returns nothing!

Comment: well instead of executing the block of code you can simple replace the inside of the Task.Run with `myModel.ExecuteMethod()`. Whether it returns something or none doesn't matter.

Comment: I updated my Controller method as following. When the code is executing "processgallery", any call to this API method doesnt come until this is finished. 
        public async Task<ActionResult> Api()
        {
            if (Model.Api == "processgallery")
            {
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Model.UpdateGallery();
                });
                return null;
            }
            else return CallApi();
        }

Comment: Obviously it won't continue because the purpose of asynchronous programming is to allow your code to proceed while the other is processing but it won't allow you to exit the method just yet, it will wait for every work to complete which is not your desired behavior. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @KMX I updated my answer in an approach to satisfy your need.

Comment: Well what i want is that the ExportData method should keep working and other Ajax call that inquires about that stats should be able to respond back to the requestee. In contrasts the ExportData holds entire sever and doesnt come back unless it has finished and the other stats requests are not entertained during that time... Do i need to process this in a separate App Pool?

Comment: @KMX since this is web, I would highly suggest using javascript to show a loading overlay while the ajax call continues. I'm guessing you are using `HTTP POST` to generate something followed by an `HTTP GET` for file download.